# How to access loopback adapter from another PC on my LAN

Tags: networking, tcp, ports

I have installed MS Loop-back adapter and have given it a static IP: 10.10.10.9

my laptop is configured as 10.10.10.30 , and my gateway is 10.10.10.1

i can ping the loop-back NIC from my laptop, but not from any other machine on the LAN. i am trying to beat the 65k port limitation by seeing if i can have virtual IP addresses on one machine and each can then give me 65k ports

thanks.

Comment: Hmm, isn't loopback supposed to be 127.0.0.0/8 and be accessible from *local machine* only? Seems you are confusing this with an *alias* for existing physical network card.

Comment: I guess so. ok, how do i hook up a virtual IP address on a windows machine? will that work for my scenario?

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this one - CharlesO - did you ever find one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By very definition, you CANNOT talk to a loopback adapter from any other machine but your own.

If on Linux, you could bridge it to a physical adapter, such as eth0, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: I need to have multiple IP addresses on he same machine.

then i can run each instance of my code listening on each IP, so if i send requests in turn to each of these "virtual IPs" from another location on my lan, each instance should be able to correctly respond to it's particular requests

Comment: @CharlesO: you can add as many IPs as you want to the physical adapter, Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://www.rasyid.net/2007/06/12/setting-multiple-ip-ip-alias-in-windows-xp/) for setting up IP alias on Windows (disclaimer - I don't own any windows machines, so can't really verify this).

Answer (score 0):

You can ping your Loopback interface from LAN by installing Remote and Routing Access role on the server.  After installing the R&S role on the server , configure LAN routing feature.  It will start pinging from LAN.  I have done this practically in my environment.